# How to Transform Spark Dataframe column for integer value toHH:MM:SS?

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I use spark with scala

```
val text = file.map(line=>line.split(" "))
.map(userRecord => (userRecord(0).trim.toInt,
      userRecord(1).trim.toInt, userRecord(2).trim.toDouble,userRecord(3).trim.toDouble,userRecord(4).trim.toDouble))
.toDF("time","nodeID","posX", "posY","speed")
```

i would to transdorm column time the type string to value toHH:MM:SS

time is second

```
+-----+------+--------+-----+-----+--------+------+
| time|nodeID|    posX| posY|speed|    date|period|
+-----+------+--------+-----+-----+--------+------+
|29220|   148|  5316.2|500.0|59.04|7/5/2010|   556|
```

Comment: can you share some lines of your text file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can define a `udf` function to format the seconds into *HH:MM:ss* as

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
def timeOfDay = udf((seconds: Long) => {
  val df = new java.text.SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss")
  df.setTimeZone(java.util.TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT"))
  df.format(seconds*1000)
})
```

and then call the `udf` function as

```
df.withColumn("time", timeOfDay(col("time")))
  .show(false)
```

which should give you

```
+--------+------+------+-----+-----+--------+------+
|time    |nodeID|posX  |posY |speed|date    |period|
+--------+------+------+-----+-----+--------+------+
|08:07:00|148   |5316.2|500.0|59.04|7/5/2010|556   |
+--------+------+------+-----+-----+--------+------+
```

You can do the same with *Java8 LocalTime* as

```
import java.time.LocalTime
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
def timeOfDay = udf((seconds: Long) => LocalTime.ofSecondOfDay(seconds).toString)
```

this however will *not include 0 time*.